# Loading images from folder path into a grid view, Android

Tags: android, gridview, directory

Hello im stuck at a bit of a problem. I can´t find a working example that allows me to load all
the images from one folder into a grid view.
I have a working grid view but i have to load the images via a int array with R.drawable.theImageName
What i need is a funktion that can load all the images to the grid without having to know the name of the image. 
I have followed this tutorial to create the grid view http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y75i3U7X-ng

Tnx for the help
And im a bit new to app programming os if i forgot something, just tell me and i'll try to paste the code.

```
GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.car_gridView);
    gv.setAdapter(new CarImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
```

.

```
private Context context;
public CarImageAdapter(Context applicationContext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context = applicationContext;
    }
```

.

```
    public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup parrent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView iv;
    if(contentView != null)
    {
        iv = (ImageView) contentView;
    }
    else
    {
        iv = new ImageView(context);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        iv.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

    }

    iv.setImageResource(car_images[position]);  
    return iv;
}
```

Im using this to create and save images.

```
    public void captureImage()
{
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_resultimage);

    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Upgrade_rim";
    imageFolderPath = root + "/car_images";
    File imagesFolder = new File(imageFolderPath);
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();


    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    imageName = "car_"+timeStamp +".png";


    File image = new File(imageFolderPath, imageName);
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
    imageView.setTag(imagesFolder + File.separator + imageName);
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST);

}
```

Comment: like u just want all pics from mobile IS it ?

Comment: i will give u code to get all pics thn u will able to show in grid, Is ur prob will solve thn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am listing all png files **stored in sdcard root folder**. I have successfully done this with PDF files.

```
public class Sdcard_pdf_list extends ListActivity {

    String[] pdflist;
    File[] imagelist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) 
            {
                return ((name.endsWith(".png")));
            }

        });

        pdflist = new String[imagelist.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++) {

            pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();

        }
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));

    }

}
```

*If you any have doubt please fill free to inform.*

Comment: i have used here list activity. you can also use gridview instead.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on were i should put the filepath when i do something like 
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Upgrade_rim/car_images";

Answer (score 0):

> One option is to use Assets folder.

Put your all images in one folder say "products" in assets folder.

I have use ImageView to show images. You can change it to gridview accordingly.

And Here you go:

```
public class Assets_Folder_Img extends Activity 
{

    ArrayList<String> arr_Img = new ArrayList<String>();
    String ASSET_FOLDER_NAME="products";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_assets__folder__img);

        get_images_in_List(ASSET_FOLDER_NAME);
        setImages();
    }

    void setImages()
    {

        InputStream is = null;

        for(int i=0;i<arr_Img.size();i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                is = getAssets().open(ASSET_FOLDER_NAME+"/" +arr_Img.get(i));
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);

                ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
                image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(120,120));
                image.setImageBitmap(bit);
                ll.addView(image);

        }
    }

     private void get_images_in_List(String folderName) 
        {
            try 
            {
                String [] list = getAssets().list(folderName);

                    arr_Img.addAll(Arrays.asList(list));
                    Log.e("log", "size is "+arr_Img.size());
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}
```

Putting images in assets is only for few images to store perpose.  Otherwise it will give load to application.